# how to resize my main partition/ complete delete old one?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, gparted

I dual booted with Xubuntu and Elementary to try it out but didn't like it. Now I want to delete Elementary completely. i downloaded Gparted but I can't delete some partitions because they're locked.[image]

Comment: From a live session, you need to eliminate /dev/sda5, then reduce /dev/sda2,  increase /dev/sda1 and recreate /dev/sda5.

Answer (score 0):

You can righ-click swap and choos "swap off". Swap is used by the system you're currently running. This is why you can't change it while your system is running.

It isn't recommended to change something on a disk your system is using and you can't remove the lock from `/dev/sda1` since this is the partition your system is running on.

Boot into a live session and choose "swap off" to remove all locks.